# How to use a cell's value (string) as part of a formula in Excel (not within a macro)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to sum a range of values in Excel based on one criterion.

So I want to sum say range `B1:B10` based on values of range `A1:A10` if the range `A1:A10` answers to some criterion e.g. contains the words `"apple - juice fresh"` or `"banana"`

So the formula would look like :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A1:A10;{"apple - juice fresh";"banana"};B1:B10))
```

This works as desired. Now, I don't want to have the list hardcoded in the formula. I want the list somewhere in a cell. Say cell `C1`. And so the cell `C1` contains as a value :

```
{"apple - juice fresh";"banana"}
```

and I want the formula to be something like :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A1:A10;C1;B1:B10))
```

But this does not work. How can I achieve this ? I tried `CONCATENATE(C1)` but it does not work.

Herebelow is a sample of what I would like

[image]

Comment: Have a look at `FILTERXML()` to break down the list into seperate elements. If you go this way, I'd stick to a single delimiter without the opening and closing brackets or the quotes. Another option using `ISNUMBER()` and `FIND()` combinations. Do you have a little bit of sample data to work with? Including your desired results.

Comment: I added a picture to illustrate

Comment: Oke, you got a nice answer down by Harun24HR. What version of Excel have you got? You are using `SUMPRODUCT()` so assume you won't have access to the new dynamic arrays?

Comment: does the list need to be in one cell, not in a range? otherwise you can do =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A1:A10,C1:C2,B1:B10)) where c1=apple and c2=banana

Comment: I have added `SUMPRODUCT()` for `Non 365` version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `FILTER()` then `SUM()` with `Excel O365`

```
=SUM(FILTER(B2:B8,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2:A8,D2))))
```

If you don't have `O365` then try `SUMPRODUCT()` like

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2:A8,D2)),B2:B8)
```

[image]

> Edit: If that is the case then go with `FILTERXML()`. Give a try on

```
=SUM(FILTER(B2:B8,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A2:A8,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,"{",""),"}",""),CHAR(34),""),", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),0))))
```

[image]

Comment: That was smart. Unfortunately I have apparently an edge case where this breaks. Namely with multiple words e.g. apple juice fresh & apple juice. If I put apple juice fresh, the method also takes into account apple juice and that is not desired. I have updated the question accordingly

Comment: @FenryrMKIII What is your excel version?

Comment: Version 2103 build 13901.20400 (Office 365 Enterprise)

Comment: @FenryrMKIII Can you please try my edited answer?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer. Works. But Excel is officially a nightmare for such easy operations ... :)

Comment: If you put them to separate cells then it would be easier.